# AJAX + ASP.net to retrieve data from Sql Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, ajax

I'm looking to dynamically control a set of drop downs so that they'll filter their items after another drop down's index has been changed.

I'm working in C#/ASP.net and it would be great if I could get the necessary data straight from Sql Server. I suppose I could generate an xml file whenever new data is uploaded to the server but that sounds like a pain.

Is there an obvious way to do what I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [CascadingDropDown Control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx).  It's part of the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange event of one drop down and on the event you can change the another  dropdown contents using ajax